# How can i allow user to enter only 10 digits number

Tags: html, input

I am trying to validate my HTML input with the pattern attribute.but it is not working ..

```
enter code here :
```

```html
<input type="number" maxLength="10" placeholder="Enter ABHA Address" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" name="ABHA Address" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
   <input
    type="text"
    maxLength="10"
    placeholder="Enter ABHA Address"
    pattern="\d{10}"
    name="ABHA Address"
    oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"
  />
```